# Visual Basic como pasar un objeto range como argumento al llamar un procedimiento diferente

Tags: excel, visual

El código siguiente me falla en la línea que llama a rutina2 dando error:

> error 424 "se requiere un objeto"

¿Qué estoy escribiendo mal?

```
Sub rutina1() 
    Dim argumento As Range 
    Set argumento = Range("A1") 
    MsgBox (argumento.Value) 'esto es nada mas comprobacion rutina2 (argumento)
End Sub
Sub rutina2(entrada As Range) 
    MsgBox (entrada.Address) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema no lo tienes en el sub o el código que nos has pasado. Lo tienes a la hora de llamar el sub y al pasar el parámetro.

Tendrias que llamarlo de esta forma desde el codigo:

```
rutina2 argumento'lo que tengas que passar como parametro
```

Ejemplo de prueba :

```
Sub rutina1()
Dim argumento As Range
Set argumento = Range("A1")
MsgBox (argumento.Value) 'esto es nada mas comprobacion rutina2 (argumento)
rutina2 argumento


 End Sub
   Sub rutina2(entrada As Range)
  MsgBox (entrada.Address)
    
   
   End Sub
```